# Elements of The Excentral triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am learning geometry and found the following question which I partially solved.
I want to see the method of approach taken out here in **StackExchange**.

The problem goes as follows:

The triangle formed by joining the excentres $I_1,  \ I_2, \ I_3 \ $of a triangle **ABC** (with elements as *a,b,c, A,B,C* and *R,s* denotes the circumradius and semi perimeter respectively) in pairs is called the *excentral triangle* of the triangle **ABC**. Show that

(i) its angles are $\frac{\pi-A}{2}, \ \frac{\pi-B}{2}, \ \frac{\pi-C}{2}$.

(ii) its sides are $4R\cos\frac{A}{2}, \ 4R\cos\frac{B}{2}, \ 4R\cos\frac{C}{2}$.

(iii) its circumradius is $2R$.

(iv) its inradius is $2R(\sum_{cyc}\sin\frac{A}{2} -1)$.

(v)its area is $2Rs$.

**Edit** As per username **Blue**'s suggestion (I appreciate it as he is helping me get accustomed to **StackExchange**) I am posting my partial accomplishment.
(i) A little bit of angle chasing does the job.

Then I noticed that **ABC**'s circumcircle is the incircle of the *excentral triangle*.

Comment: Please learn this from a textbook of trigonometry or from internet. Goodluck!

Comment: You note that you have "partially solved" these items. You should outline what method(s) you used ---and where you got stuck--- so that answerers don't waste their valuable time explaining things you already know, and can address specific points of confusion.

Comment: The first part is trivial through angle chasing.
Now i was trying to do it through this way:
As the circumcentre of the triangle **ABC** is the incentre of the excentral triangle i tried to formulate the circumradius through it but got stuck

Comment: You should include your methods and issues in your problem statement, instead of in the comments where they might be overlooked. (BTW: If the first part (or any part) is indeed "trivial" to you, then you shouldn't include it here at all, since any answer is inherently a waste of time.)

Comment: I think its a duty for a problem solver to supply the whole problem rather than pick a part which he cant do.

Comment: Problem solver has no duty at all.